# #include <SDL2/SDL.h> giving "pp_file_not_found" in VIM

Tags: c++, macos, vim, sdl-2

I was facing a problem while using SDL2, `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` for the first time on my mac m1.

Whenever I was doing `:w` to save the file, I think ALE in VIM says **" pp_file_not_found: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found "**.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeZ3I.png

**I had downloaded and moved SDL2.framework into my /Library/Frameworks directory.**

While compiling on terminal, I use:

```bash
g++ -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2 file.cpp
```

Is this the correct way??
This creates `./a.out`, and runs just fine.

**How do I configure VIM and ALE to find and extract constructs from include statements and Libraries like SDL2?**

:ALEInfo

```
ALEInfo
 Current Filetype: cpp
Available Linters: ['cc', 'ccls', 'clangcheck', 'clangd', 'clangtidy', 'clazy', 'cppcheck', 'cpplint', 'cquery', 'cspell', 'flawfinder']
   Linter Aliases:
'cc' -> ['gcc', 'clang', 'g++', 'clang++']
  Enabled Linters: ['cc', 'ccls', 'clangcheck', 'clangd', 'clangtidy', 'clazy', 'cppcheck', 'cpplint', 'cquery', 'cspell', 'flawfinder']
  Ignored Linters: []
 Suggested Fixers:
  'astyle' - Fix C/C++ with astyle.
  'clang-format' - Fix C/C++ and cuda files with clang-format.
  'clangtidy' - Fix C/C++ and ObjectiveC files with clang-tidy.
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
  'uncrustify' - Fix C, C++, C#, ObjectiveC, ObjectiveC++, D, Java, Pawn, and VALA files with uncrustify.
 Linter Variables:

let g:ale_cpp_cc_executable = '<auto>'
let g:ale_cpp_cc_options = '-std=c++17 -fsanitize=address -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Werror -DONPC -O2 -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/ -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SD
L2'
let g:ale_cpp_ccls_executable = 'ccls'
let g:ale_cpp_ccls_init_options = {}
let g:ale_cpp_clangcheck_executable = 'clang-check'
let g:ale_cpp_clangcheck_options = ''
let g:ale_cpp_clangd_executable = 'clangd'
let g:ale_cpp_clangd_options = ''
let g:ale_cpp_clangtidy_checks = []
let g:ale_cpp_clangtidy_executable = 'clang-tidy'
let g:ale_cpp_clangtidy_extra_options = ''
let g:ale_cpp_clangtidy_options = ''
let g:ale_cpp_clazy_checks = ['level1']
let g:ale_cpp_clazy_executable = 'clazy-standalone'
let g:ale_cpp_clazy_options = ''
let g:ale_cpp_cppcheck_executable = 'cppcheck'
let g:ale_cpp_cppcheck_options = '--enable=style'
let g:ale_cpp_cpplint_executable = 'cpplint'
let g:ale_cpp_cpplint_options = ''
let g:ale_cpp_cquery_cache_directory = '/Users/vishalpaudel/.cache/cquery'
let g:ale_cpp_cquery_executable = 'cquery'
let g:ale_cpp_flawfinder_executable = 'flawfinder'
let g:ale_cpp_flawfinder_minlevel = 1
let g:ale_cpp_flawfinder_options = ''
 Global Variables:

let g:ale_cache_executable_check_failures = v:null
let g:ale_change_sign_column_color = 0
let g:ale_command_wrapper = ''
let g:ale_completion_delay = v:null
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 0
let g:ale_completion_max_suggestions = v:null
let g:ale_disable_lsp = 0
let g:ale_echo_cursor = 1
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'Error'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_echo_msg_info_str = 'Info'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'Warning'
let g:ale_enabled = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 0
let g:ale_fixers = {}
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = 0
let g:ale_lint_delay = 200
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_filetype_changed = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_insert_leave = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 'normal'
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {}
let g:ale_linters = {}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 0
let g:ale_linters_ignore = {}
let g:ale_list_vertical = 0
let g:ale_list_window_size = 10
let g:ale_loclist_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_max_buffer_history_size = 20
let g:ale_max_signs = -1
let g:ale_maximum_file_size = v:null
let g:ale_open_list = 0
let g:ale_pattern_options = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options_enabled = v:null
let g:ale_root = {}
let g:ale_set_balloons = 0
let g:ale_set_highlights = 1
let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
let g:ale_set_signs = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 0
let g:ale_sign_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_info = '--'
let g:ale_sign_offset = 1000000
let g:ale_sign_style_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_highlight_linenrs = 0
let g:ale_statusline_format = v:null
let g:ale_type_map = {}
let g:ale_use_global_executables = v:null
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_blank_lines = 1
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_whitespace = 1
  Command History:

(executable check - success) clang++
(finished - exit code 1) ['/bin/zsh', '-c', '''clang++'' -S -x c++ -o /dev/null -iquote ''/Users/vishalpaudel/Documents/SDL_tutorial/lazyFoo_SDL_tutrial'' -std=c++17 -fsanitize=address -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra
-Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Werror -DONPC -O2 -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/ -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2 - < ''/var/folders/8k/ggpn5rp16kddhp7gv3hz_tcc0000gn/T/vnX2hNq/2/01_hello_SDL.
cpp''']

<<<OUTPUT STARTS>>>
clang: error: -framework SDL2: 'linker' input unused [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]
<<<OUTPUT ENDS>>>


(executable check - failure) ccls
(executable check - failure) clang-check
(executable check - success) clangd
(executable check - failure) clang-tidy
(executable check - failure) clazy-standalone
(executable check - failure) cppcheck
(executable check - failure) cpplint
(executable check - failure) cquery
(executable check - failure) cspell
(executable check - failure) flawfinder
(started) ['/bin/zsh', '-c', '''clangd''']
(executable check - failure) ccls
(executable check - failure) cquery
```

My ~/.vimrc:

```
" .vimrc of Bo Liu
" {{{
" https://github.com/hmybmny/vimrc

set nocompatible

" }}}

" VIM-PLUG BLOCK
" {{{


if has('python3')
endif

silent! if plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Colors
Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plug 'tomasr/molokai'
Plug 'colepeters/spacemacs-theme.vim'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'

" Editing
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plug 'sjl/gundo.vim'
Plug 'matze/vim-move'
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plug 'kana/vim-operator-user'
Plug 'gcmt/wildfire.vim'
Plug 'lilydjwg/fcitx.vim'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'derekwyatt/vim-protodef', { 'for': ['c', 'cpp', 'objc'] }
Plug 'suan/vim-instant-markdown', { 'for': 'markdown' }

" Navigation
Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar', { 'on': 'TagbarToggle' }
Plug 'derekwyatt/vim-fswitch', { 'for': ['c', 'cpp', 'objc'] }
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on': 'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'dyng/ctrlsf.vim'
Plug 'fholgado/minibufexpl.vim'

" View
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'

" Linting
Plug 'w0rp/ale'

"cd ~
"mkdir ycm_build
"cd ycm_build/
"cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DPATH_TO_LLVM_ROOT=~/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.9.1-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-16.04 . ~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp
"cmake --build . --target ycm_core

"Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

function! BuildYCM(info)
if a:info.status == 'installed' || a:info.force
  !./install.py --clang-completer
endif
endfunction

Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': function('BuildYCM') }

call plug#end()
endif

" }}}

" BASIC SETTINGS
" {{{

let mapleader = ';'

set encoding=utf-8

" Allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" Store lots of :cmdline history
set history=500

" Show line numbers
set nu

set nowrap

" Autoindent when starting new line
set autoindent
set smartindent
set lazyredraw

" Ignore case when searching
set ignorecase 

" Don't ignore case when search has capital letter
set smartcase

" Enable highlighted case-insensitive incremential search
set incsearch

" Enble search highlighting
set hlsearch

" Always show window statuses
set laststatus=2

" Statusline style
set statusline=
set statusline+=%7*\[%n]                                  "buffernr
set statusline+=%1*\ %<%F\                                "File+path
set statusline+=%2*\ %y\                                  "FileType
set statusline+=%3*\ %{''.(&fenc!=''?&fenc:&enc).''}      "Encoding
set statusline+=%3*\ %{(&bomb?\",BOM\":\"\")}\            "Encoding2
set statusline+=%4*\ %{&ff}\                              "FileFormat (dos/unix..) 
set statusline+=%8*\ %=\ row:%l/%L\ (%p%%)\             "Rownumber/total (%)
set statusline+=%9*\ col:%c\                            "Colnr
set statusline+=%0*\ \ %m%r%w\ %P\ \                      "Modified? Readonly? Top/bot.

" Show the size of block one selected in visual mode
set showcmd

" Hide buffers
set hidden
set visualbell

" Indent using four spaces
set expandtab smarttab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4

set gcr=a:block-blinkon0

set guioptions-=l
set guioptions-=L
set guioptions-=r
set guioptions-=R
set guioptions-=m
set guioptions-=T

function! ToggleFullscreen()
call system("wmctrl -ir " . v:windowid . " -b toggle,fullscreen")
endf

map <silent> <F11> :call ToggleFullscreen()<CR>
imap <silent> <F11> <esc>:call ToggleFullscreen()<CR>
" autocmd VimEnter * call ToggleFullscreen()

" Show the line and column number of the cursor position
set ruler

" Highlight line under cursor
set cursorline
set cursorcolumn


" }}}

" MAPPINGS
" {{{

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" Basic mappings
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

" Profile
iabbrev @@ hmybmny@gmail.com
iabbrev @b hmybmny.com

" Edit myvimrc
nnoremap <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
nnoremap <leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<cr>

" Edit
nnoremap <leader>" viw<esc>a"<esc>hbi"<esc>lel

" Save
inoremap <C-s>     <C-O>:w<cr>
nnoremap <C-s>     :w<cr>
nnoremap <leader>w :w<cr>

" Copy
vnoremap <Leader>y "+y
nmap <Leader>p "+p

" Quit
nnoremap <Leader>q :q<cr>
nnoremap <Leader>Q :qa!<cr>

" Movement in insert mode
inoremap <C-h> <C-o>h
inoremap <C-j> <C-o>j
inoremap <C-k> <C-o>k
inoremap <C-l> <C-o>a
inoremap <C-^> <C-o><C-^>

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" Quickfix
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

nnoremap ]q :cnext<cr>zz
nnoremap [q :cprev<cr>zz

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" <tab> / <s-tab> | Circular windows navigation
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

nnoremap <tab>   <c-w>w
nnoremap <S-tab> <c-w>W
nnoremap <Leader>hw <C-W>h
nnoremap <Leader>jw <C-W>j
nnoremap <Leader>kw <C-W>k
nnoremap <Leader>lw <C-W>l

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" :CopyRTF
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function! s:colors(...)
return filter(map(filter(split(globpath(&rtp, 'colors/*.vim'), "\n"),
    \                  'v:val !~ "^/usr/"'),
    \           'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t:r")'),
    \       '!a:0 || stridx(v:val, a:1) >= 0')
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
endfunction

" <F8> | Color scheme selector
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
"  
set background=dark

let g:molokai_original = 1
colorschem molokai

function! s:rotate_colors()
  if !exists('s:colors')
    let s:colors = s:colors()
  endif
  let name = remove(s:colors, 0)
  call add(s:colors, name)
  set background=dark
  execute 'colorscheme' name
  redraw
  echo name
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <F8> :call <SID>rotate_colors()<cr>
inoremap <silent> <F8> <esc>:call <SID>rotate_colors()<cr>

" }}}

" PLUGINS
" {{{

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" ultisnips
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["mysnippets"]
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<leader><tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<leader><tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<leader><s-tab>"

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" vim-multiple-cursors
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

let g:multi_cursor_next_key='<S-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_skip_key='<S-k>'

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" vim-move
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

let g:move_key_modifier = 'C'

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" auto-pairs
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" vim-operator-user
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" wildfire.vim
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

map <SPACE> <Plug>(wildfire-fuel)
vmap <C-SPACE> <Plug>(wildfire-water)

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" indentLine
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

let g:indentLine_char = '│'

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" tarbar
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

inoremap <F2> <esc>:TagbarToggle<cr>
nnoremap <F2> :TagbarToggle<cr>

let tagbar_left=1
let tagbar_width=32
let g:tagbar_sort = 0
let g:tagbar_compact=1
let g:tagbar_type_cpp = {
 \ 'ctagstype' : 'c++',
 \ 'kinds'     : [
     \ 'c:classes:0:1',
     \ 'd:macros:0:1',
     \ 'e:enumerators:0:0', 
     \ 'f:functions:0:1',
     \ 'g:enumeration:0:1',
     \ 'l:local:0:1',
     \ 'm:members:0:1',
     \ 'n:namespaces:0:1',
     \ 'p:functions_prototypes:0:1',
     \ 's:structs:0:1',
     \ 't:typedefs:0:1',
     \ 'u:unions:0:1',
     \ 'v:global:0:1',
     \ 'x:external:0:1'
 \ ],
 \ 'sro'        : '::',
 \ 'kind2scope' : {
     \ 'g' : 'enum',
     \ 'n' : 'namespace',
     \ 'c' : 'class',
     \ 's' : 'struct',
     \ 'u' : 'union'
 \ },
 \ 'scope2kind' : {
     \ 'enum'      : 'g',
     \ 'namespace' : 'n',
     \ 'class'     : 'c',
     \ 'struct'    : 's',
     \ 'union'     : 'u'
 \ }
\ }

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" vim-fswitch
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

nmap <silent> <Leader>fs :FSHere<cr>

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" vim-protodef
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

let g:protodefprotogetter='~/.vim/plugged/vim-protodef/pullproto.pl'
let g:disable_protodef_sorting=1

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" nerdcommenter
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" nerdtree
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

inoremap <F3> <esc>:NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <F3> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

let NERDTreeWinSize=22
let NERDTreeWinPos="right"
let NERDTreeShowHidden=0
let NERDTreeMinimalUI=1
let NERDTreeAutoDeleteBuffer=1

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" vim-instant-markdown
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.md set filetype=markdown

let g:instant_markdown_slow = 1
let g:instant_markdown_autostart = 0

nnoremap <Leader>md :InstantMarkdownPreview<CR>


" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" vim-fugitive
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" vim-gitgutter
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

set updatetime=250

set signcolumn=yes

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" ale
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" minibufexpl
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

inoremap <F4> <esc>:MBEToggle<cr>
nnoremap <F4> :MBEToggle<cr>

nnoremap ]b :bnext<cr>
nnoremap [b :bprev<cr>

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" gundo.vim
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

nnoremap <Leader>ud :GundoToggle<CR>

set sessionoptions="blank,globals,localoptions,tabpages,sesdir,folds,help,options,resize,winpos,winsize"

if !strlen(finddir('~/.vim/undofiles'))
echo "undofiles[~/.vim/undofiles] not found. Now it's being created. Press ENTER or type command to continue."
!mkdir -p ~/.vim/undofiles
endif

if v:version >= 703
set undodir=~/.vim/undofiles
set undofile
set colorcolumn=+1 
endif

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" ctrlsf.vim
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

nnoremap <c-f> :CtrlSF<CR>

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" ctrlp.vim
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

" Disable output, vcs, archive, rails, temp and backup files
set wildignore+=*.o,*.out,*.obj,.git,*.pyc,*.class
set wildignore+=*.zip,*.tar.gz,*.tar.bz2,*.rar,*.tar.xz
set wildignore+=*.swp,*~,._*
set wildignore+=*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip     " MacOSX/Linux

let g:ctrlp_map = '<s-p>'
let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlP'
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = '\v[\/]\.(git|hg|svn)$'
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
  \ 'dir':  '\v[\/]\.(git|hg|svn|vendor/bundle/*\|vendor/cache/*\|public\|spec)$',
  \ 'file': '\v\.(exe|so|dll|swp|log|jpg|png|json)$',
  \ }

" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
" YouCompleteMe
" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

set completeopt-=preview

nnoremap <leader>jc :YcmCompleter GoToDeclaration<CR>
nnoremap <leader>jd :YcmCompleter GoToDefinition<CR>
inoremap <leader>; <C-x><C-o>

"run and compile cpp
nnoremap <f8> :!g++ -o  %:r.out % -std=c++14<Enter>
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <f9> :!%:r.out<CR>


let g:ycm_complete_in_comments=1
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf=0
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files=0
let g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion=1
let g:ycm_cache_omnifunc=0
let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax=1

let g:ale_cpp_cc_options = '-std=c++17 -fsanitize=address -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Werror -DONPC -O2 -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/ -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2'

" }}}
```

~/.zshrc

```bash
alias python="python3.10"
alias pip="pip3"

alias vim="/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/Vim"

alias cmake="/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake"

alias g++="g++ -std=c++17 -fsanitize=address -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Werror -DONPC -O2"  # -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/ -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2"

alias clang++="clang++ -std=c++17 -fsanitize=address -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Werror -DONPC -O2"  # -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/ -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2"

alias gcc="gcc -std=c++17 -fsanitize=address -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Werror -DONPC -O2" # -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/ -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2"

export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"

export LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/:$LIBRARY_PATH"

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export PATH=$HOME/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin:$PATH 

export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
  export EDITOR='vim'
else
  export EDITOR='mvim'
fi

# For file icons in ls -a
if [ -x "$(command -v colorls)" ]; then
    alias ls="colorls"
    alias la="colorls -al"
fi

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working,

Use this, instead of `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`:

```cpp
#include <SDL.h>
```

Short answer is, add these few lines at the end of both `~/.zshrc`, and `~/.zshprofile`:

```bash
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/./:${PATH}"
export PATH

LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/:${LIBRARY_PATH}"
export LIBRARY_PATH

CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Nothing wrong with above setup, do not copy the above setup though. Do have a look, you might find something useful.

**DISCLAIMER**: I can sense that I have done this in a hacky way and alot of the things that are happening I do not understand fully.

I think the compiler searches for header files in the current PATH variable, so appending the Library location in the PATH, might just help in that.